# Remove css module object from js

Tags: javascript, webpack, compiler-optimization, react-css-modules

I have webpack (v5) typescript(v4) react(v17) project which uses css modules.
When I bundle it with -production flag i have output with:

```
23254:(t,e,n)=>{"use strict";n.r(e),n.d(e,{default:()=>i});const i={backOrdersCaution:"b_F-d b_G-d",cartForm:"b_H-d"}}
```

I see that this is dictionary for javascript to translate project class name to css module class name. But why it does not compile directly into className jsx property? Something like:

```
<Component className="b_F-d b_G-d"/>
```

Instead of

```
<Component className="modules[23254].backOrdersCaution/>
```

And just remove dictionary object from js.
It would reduce js bundle size and increase performance...

Is there any decision to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Every similar styling solution does not care about that. There are other libraries like https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx which use a fundamentally different approach.

Keep in mind that nothing will be more performant than global styles yet.

In the future, [Next.js](https://nextjs.org) may provide something that resolves all styling problems with its own compiler.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify it to your regular classname by a bit change in webpack config:

```
modules: {
    localIdentName: '[local]'
},
```

By default it will be 'hash' for production env.

You can check details https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#modules

Comment: I'm talking about removing object with dictionary from javascript in webpack compile time